# How to repaint ALL visible components of Java Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a JFrame which allows user to adjust colors. This colors are set into static fields of class `Colors` using reflection. Here is the `Colors` class:

```
public class Colors {

    public static Color TextBackground = Color.black;
    public static Color TextForeground = Color.white;
}
```

There are many other components, located in several JFrame's, and they all use fields of `Colors` class. When I manually cause them to repaint (e.g. by resizing), they all repaint correctly.

But how can I cause all other components to repaint automatically?

I tried something that seems dirty changing LookAndFeel, but it didn't work:

```
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getLookAndFeel());
```

**Update:** I need to repaint components in all **other** JFrame's, that are currently visible.

Comment: _they all use fields of Colors class_ what a terrible design ... What do you mean by _automatically_? Loop over the list of frames and repaint them is the minimum you need to do after changing the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will repaint all owner-less windows

```
Window[] windows = Frame.getOwnerlessWindows();
for (int i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
    windows[i].repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call a method on your JFrame to let it know that its content needs to be repainted when you change colors. I believe the correct method is `revalidate()`, but `repaint()` may work as well. For more information on painting in Swing, try looking here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I asked. Please see clarification in the update.

Comment: In that case, maybe maintain a collection of all of your JFrames and, when the color is changed, iterate over the list and have each JFrame repaint?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't have a good handle on which components might be out there using your `Colors` class. In this case I'd give `Colors` the ability to support `PropertyChangeListener`s.

```
class Colors {

  private static Colors instance = new Colors();

  public static Colors getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }

  private Color textBackground = Color.black;

  private PropertyChangeSupport backgroundProp = new PropertyChangeSupport(textBackground);

  public void setBackgroundColor(Color color) {
    this.textBackground = color;
  }

  public void addBackgroundListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    backgroundProp.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
  }
}
```

Then whenever a component uses `Colors` define it as a `PropertyChangeListener` and let `Colors` know about it.

```
class MyTextField extends JTextField implements PropertyChangeListener {

  public MyTextField() {
    super();
    Colors.getInstance().addBackgroundListener(this);
  }

  public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    Color background = (Color)evt.getNewValue();
    setBackground(background);
    repaint();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a class extend JPanel and override the 
public void paintComponent function.

when you call frame.repaint(), it will reference code in paintComponent.

Answer (score 1):

> This colors are set into static fields of class Colors using reflection.

This is your problem.  Rather than a) storing the colors in static variables, b) using reflection to update these values, or c) looping over the array of ownerless windows, use Swing as it's designed.  It's a little more code, but it will work cleaner and more efficiently do what you want.

1. Don't use reflection.  Create an actual interface for users to update color values, in an instance rather than a static, and tie this into the frame your users will work with to specify the colors they want.
2. Put methods on your ColorManager object that accept [`ChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) objects.  At a minimum, simply create at `addChangeListener()` method, but alternatively you could add more granular control by defining several methods, `addBackgroundListener()`, `addForegroundListener()`, etc.  These methods should store a list of registered listeners which will be notified when the associated action (the user updates the color) is performed.
3. Make your windows implement the ChangeListener interface, and register them with the ColorManager object.  When the `stateChanged()` method is called your windows can handle it, updating the color and calling `repaint()` in the same place.

The key advantage here is that now each class is doing exactly what it's supposed to, and has no unexpected side-effects on other classes.  The ColorManager is directly (as opposed to via reflection) updated by the user, it notifies exactly the objects that have explicitly asked to be notified (which can still be all windows, if that's what you want), and those objects can do with that information what they need to, whether that's repainting or doing something more complex.